# Tuleap - Assign back to Artifact Submitter

Tags: live, artifact, tuleap

in the field usage section of tuleap, i have selected bind to users option, in that i selected list of groups available and also artifact_submitter option.

So,when a submitter(user1) fills the task and assign it to the user2, the assigned person couldn't assign back exactly to the particular person(user1), who submitted the artifact.When user2 selects a assigned to option he can see the artifact_submitter along with the usergroups involved in the section.

In our office we have some 150 users who will submit a artifact and assign it to the project lead user, in turn the project lead couldn't assign back to the exact user who submitted it.

When he clicks the assigned to option, he could able to see all the 150 users available for that user group.

Is there a option where one can assign back to the exact user whoever submitted the artifact.(like we have correspondence button in Codesk tool)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sadly no, this is not possible at the moment. What you can do is use an Openlist field instead, which does not solve your issue but make it easier to select one person in a list of 150 name.

Comment: So, if this is the case,when i select a single name from openlist section and give submit.Will that artifact be available in the My artifact section of his personal page of the selected person.

Comment: Yes, but you have to go in the tracker semantic and fill the "Contributor/assignee" part.

Comment: ya i tried to do that, but in the semantic and fill the "Contributor/assignee" part, i couldn,t able to select the Assignee(Label name for openlist section)

Comment: Mhmm, indeed you can't. I was pretty sure you could. You should submit a request to add this possibility

Comment: i have submitted a request after selecting the user in the openlist field,what do you mean by submit a request to add this possibility.

Comment: I meant submitting a request to the Tuleap community here: https://tuleap.net/plugins/tracker/?tracker=140 so the Tuleap contributors can know there is a new functionnality needed for the Openlist field.